# How to intercept header "X-Total-Count" into Axios intercepter for only 1 type of requests and not all (reactJs, Json-server)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios, json-server

I am using json-server as fake API, and axios to create a paginated request to a set of data .
Here's my data from json-server

```
[{"id" : 1, "author" : "Trever"},
 {"id" : 2, "author" : "Sonya"},
 {"id" : 3, "author" : "Mark"},
 {"id" : 4, "author" : "Bob"}, {...}, {...}, ... ]
```

I have similar other resources for cars and drums too.

I created an agent file `(agent.ts)` to centralise all of my axios requests

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/';
const responseBody = ( Response : AxiosResponse ) => Response.data;

const requests = {
    get : (url : string, params? : URLSearchParams ) => axios.get(url, {params}).then(responseBody),
    post : (url : string, body : {}) => axios.post(url, body).then(responseBody),
    put : (url : string, body : {}) => axios.put(url, body).then(responseBody),
    delete : (url : string) => axios.delete(url).then(responseBody)
}

// intercepting reponse header
axios.interceptors.response.use( response => {
const totalBooks = response.headers['x-total-count'];
 if (totalBooks) console.log(JSON.parse(totalBooks), 'total books in database'); //this is working fine - (i am receiving '20', into console which is correct)
 return response;
});

const Posts = {
 get : (params : URLSearchParams) => requests.get('books', params);
}

const agent = {
Posts
};

export default agent;
```

Now I have created a slice for getting books into my component - i named it `bookSlice.ts`

here's the code to that -

```
bookSlice.ts



 interface BookState {
    loadedBooks : boolean;
    status : string;
    totalBooks : string | undefined;
    }
    
    export const booksAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Book>();

     // (i want to do something like this) - intercepting response for books only (similary I want to intercept "X-Total-Count" inside carSlice and drumSlice files as well)// 
    const XTotalCountHeader = () => {
     axios.intercepters.response.use(response => {
     const totalBooks = response.headers['x-total-count'];
     if (totalBooks) thunkAPI.dispatch(JSON.parse(totalBooks));
     return response;
    });
 }

export const fetchBooksAsync = createAsyncThunk<Book[], void, {state : RootState}>(
'books/fetchBooksAsync',
async(_, thunkAPI) => {
 const booksParams = AxiosGetParams(thunkAPI.getState().books.parameters); // this is my function to append parameters to the url string
 try{
  return await agent.Posts.get(bookParams);
 } catch(error : any) { return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({error : error.data});
});

export const bookSlice = createSlice({
name : 'books',
initialState : booksAdapter.getInitialState<BookState>({
loadedBooks : false,
status : 'idle',
totalBooks : '',
}),
reducers : {
 setTotalBooks : (state, action) => {
   state.totalBooks = action.payLoad;
 }
},
extraReducers : (builder => {
  builder.addCase(fetchBooksAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
   booksAdapter.setAll(state, action);
   state.loadedBooks = true,
   state.status = 'idle'
  });

 builder.addCase(fetchBooksAsync.pending, (state) => {
   state.status = 'pending'
  });

 builder.addCase(fetchBooksAsync.rejected, (state) => {
  state.status = 'rejected';
  });
});
});

export const { setTotalBooks } =bookSlice.actions;
```

// what i want is to get the value of the header "X-Total-Count" from json-server's response headers into some object (in this case - totalBooks ), so that I could use this object anywhere into my Application's components.//

```
Also, I have different resourses viz - books[], cars[], drums[], etc.
```

And on using -

```
  axios.intercepters.response.use(response => {
     const totalBooks = response.headers['x-total-count'];
     if (totalBooks) thunkAPI.dispatch(JSON.parse(totalBooks));
     return response;
    });

All of the responses are intercepted , and I get different numbers into the console ,like
20 //since it is total books 
3 //since it is total cars
9 //since it is total drums
```

I only want the total books into my `bookSlice.ts` ,
similarly I only want the total cars into My `carsSlice.ts`
and I only want the total drums into my `drumSlice.ts`.

**So firstly, how should I get the "X-Total-Count" from the `axios.intercepters` (if fetched in this way?) into the respective slices for books, cars, and drums respectively???**

**Secondly, I dont want to destroy the pattern I am using into my agent.ts file,
ie, I created a `responseBody` , for accumulating the `response.data`, and `requests` - object to centralise all the requests to the json - server in my agent.ts file.**
I wanted this to be followed.

And I don't want to make something like this into my either of the slices -

```
try{
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/books').then((response) => {
    thunkAPI.dispatch(setTotalBooks(response.headers['x-total-count']))
    })
    } catch(error : any) {
     return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({error : error.data });
    }
```

How either could I do this into my `agent.ts` file (if possible)?
I hope you have understood my problem.
Please suggest me some solutions to get this "X-Total-Count" values each for my books, cars, drums into their respective slices (and three different objects, so that I could use them into their respective UI Components).

Thank You, all suggestions are welcome!!